# In dplyr mutate across, is it possible to use non-referenced columns in a programmable fashion?

Tags: r, dplyr, across, mutate

Suppose I have this tibble with an arbitrary number of variable pairs x and x_var, y and y_var, etc.

```
dt <- tibble(x = 1:3,
       y = 2:4,
       z = 3:5,
       x_var = rep(0.1, 3),
       y_var = rep(0.2, 3),
       z_var = rep(0.3, 3))
```

I was attempting to calculate x + x_var, y + y_var, etc all in one go, using mutate-across.

I tried

```
tb %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = all_of(c("x", "y", "z")), 
            .names = "{col}_sum", 
            function(x) x + !!rlang::sym(paste0(cur_column(), "_var"))))
```

but this does not seem to work. I do not want to hard-code variable names and see that it can be done via pivoting, however I'm curious if mutate-across will do the trick somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If the columns are in the same order, we could do

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
   mutate(across(x:z, .names = "{.col}_sum") + 
           across(ends_with("_var")))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 9
      x     y     z x_var y_var z_var x_sum y_sum z_sum
  <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3   0.1   0.2   0.3   1.1   2.2   3.3
2     2     3     4   0.1   0.2   0.3   2.1   3.2   4.3
3     3     4     5   0.1   0.2   0.3   3.1   4.2   5.3
```

---

Or another option is to loop `across` one set and then modify the OP's code by retrieving the value of the `paste`d column name with `get`

```
dt %>% 
    mutate(across(x:z, ~ .x +  
     get(paste0(cur_column(), "_var")), .names = "{.col}_sum"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 9
      x     y     z x_var y_var z_var x_sum y_sum z_sum
  <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3   0.1   0.2   0.3   1.1   2.2   3.3
2     2     3     4   0.1   0.2   0.3   2.1   3.2   4.3
3     3     4     5   0.1   0.2   0.3   3.1   4.2   5.3
```

---

Or use `dplyover`

```
library(dplyover)
library(stringr)
dt %>%
    mutate(across2(x:z, x_var:z_var, ~ .x + .y, 
     .names_fn = ~ str_replace(.x, "_._var", "_sum")))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 9
      x     y     z x_var y_var z_var x_sum y_sum z_sum
  <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3   0.1   0.2   0.3   1.1   2.2   3.3
2     2     3     4   0.1   0.2   0.3   2.1   3.2   4.3
3     3     4     5   0.1   0.2   0.3   3.1   4.2   5.3
```

---

Or this is much simpler in `base R`

```
dt[paste0(names(dt)[1:3], "_sum")] <- dt[1:3] + dt[4:6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re on the right track with `paste0(cur_column(), "_var")`.  Instead of using `sym()`, use your computed column name to index into `cur_data()`:

```
library(dplyr)

tb %>%
  mutate(across(
    .cols = c(x, y, z), 
    .fns = \(x) x + cur_data()[[paste0(cur_column(), "_var")]],
    .names = "{col}_sum"
  ))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 9
      x     y     z x_var y_var z_var x_sum y_sum z_sum
  <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3   0.1   0.2   0.3   1.1   2.2   3.3
2     2     3     4   0.1   0.2   0.3   2.1   3.2   4.3
3     3     4     5   0.1   0.2   0.3   3.1   4.2   5.3
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Are you able to see why sym() does not work in this context?

Comment: Honestly no, I would have thought your approach would work, and I’m not sure why it doesn’t.

Comment: My only vague guess is it’s something to do with the evaluation context, since you’re using it inside an anonymous function inside `across()` inside `mutate()`, all of which have their own environments and/or data masking… you could maybe look at `base::eval()` or `rlang::eval_tidy()` to specify the environment to evaluate in?